# Running out of room in /home

Tags: partitioning, mount, 22.04, fstab, home-directory

I wanted to run Ubuntu on my primary system so I installed a second hard drive, a 500GB. I let the install program do all of the partitioning. I tried to move files off of my Windows 7 drive, but I ran out of space. I went to [this website](https://superuser.com/q/468634/) as it seems to be the same thing that my system is doing. I typed `df -h` into terminal and I got this:

[image: Screenshot1]

In nano as root I edited the `/etc/fstab` file and added this line:

```
/dev/sdb1  /home  ext4  rw,relatime,acl  0  2
```

I saved it and then restarted. This made my `/home` directory inaccessible and locked up my computer. After a few tries trying to gain access to `/home`, I went back in and added # to the beginning of that line and was able gain access to `/home` again.  I used terminal to make the directory Docs in `/media/clay/Ubuntu`. I can access it, but can't do anything else with it.  It tells me that I don't have permission. I have read that I can delete the sdb1 partition and expand the sdb5, but I read that if you do that it makes it harder to update or change distributions, and I'm not sure how to proceed.  This is what my `/etc/fsta`b looks like:

[image: /etc/fstab]

It looks like it uses the UUID to identify the drive partitions, but I don't know how to find out what the id of sdb1 is or how to add it and what other information I need add to `/etc/fstab` to make it accessible.

Comment: "*how to find out what the id of sdb1*": `sudo blkid | grep sdb1`

Comment: You can move /home. To move /home uses rsync- Be sure to use parameters to preserve ownership & permissions 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving    Or you can move some data folders in /home to data partition & link folders back to /home in /, so it looks just like data is in /, but really in another partition. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk

Comment: @user535733  Thank you for that command.  It brought up the id:  dev/sdb1: LABEL="Ubuntu" UUID="26227212-cb2c-4700-99b6-0a94345e39ca" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="8762992f-01"  Now to try and figure out what else goes with it in the etc/fstab.

Comment: @Nmath  I didn't set up any partitions,  That was all ubuntu.  The drive had no partitions when I bought it and installed it.

Comment: @Nmath,  I don't know what to tell you.  I do know that sdb is a 500gb and was just installed, sda is a 1 terabyte.  sda has been in the computer since 2014.  sda has 2 partitions, the rescue partition and the primary partition.

Comment: @oldfred,  Thank you for those links.  I was just able gain permissions over the large partition so I am able to move all of my existing items out of home.  Now to move the rest off my windows drive.